# pl/pgsql: Dynamicly get a column name from a record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql

Greeting,
I want dynamicly get a column name from a record.
As showing in the code below that I created a cursor and I used a loop to process each record in that cursor by fetching each row to a record type r1.
In my table I have these columns [dlq_2000,dlq_2001,...,dlq_2017,dlq_2017].
Also I created on top of it a loop to process each column separate.

The issue I am facing is getting the field name from r1 dynamicly and I am getting this error when I run the code:

> [Err] ERROR: record "r1" has no field "'dlq_'||counter::text" CONTEXT:
>   SQL statement "SELECT ( r1."'dlq_'||counter::text" = 1 )"

Please advice how to solve this issue.

Thank you,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update()
   RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE 
cur SCROLL CURSOR   FOR select * from my_tbl;
r1 RECORD;
begin
OPEN cur ;
FOR counter IN  2000..2017 LOOP
    r1 := NULL;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO r1;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        IF (r1."'dl_'||counter::text" = 1 ) THEN
            -- do some thing
            RAISE NOTICE 'processing year of : %', counter;
        END IF;     
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
END; 

 $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the field name, or the field by-name?

Comment: @CraigRinger I am trying to get the value of column named "'dl_'||counter::text" and compare it with 1 using any method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have an easy way to just check a "variable column". There is a (not very elegant) way of achieving this result, by using a `CASE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update()
    RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE 
    cur SCROLL CURSOR   FOR select * from my_tbl;
    r1 RECORD;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur ;
    FOR counter IN  2000..2017 LOOP
        r1 := NULL;
        LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO r1;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

            IF
              (CASE counter 
                WHEN 2000 THEN r1.dl_2000
                WHEN 2001 THEN r1.dl_2001
                WHEN 2002 THEN r1.dl_2002
                WHEN 2003 THEN r1.dl_2003
                WHEN 2004 THEN r1.dl_2004
                WHEN 2005 THEN r1.dl_2005
                WHEN 2006 THEN r1.dl_2006
                WHEN 2007 THEN r1.dl_2007
                WHEN 2008 THEN r1.dl_2008
                WHEN 2009 THEN r1.dl_2009
                WHEN 2010 THEN r1.dl_2010
                WHEN 2011 THEN r1.dl_2011
                WHEN 2012 THEN r1.dl_2012
                WHEN 2013 THEN r1.dl_2013
                WHEN 2014 THEN r1.dl_2014
                WHEN 2015 THEN r1.dl_2015
                WHEN 2016 THEN r1.dl_2016
                WHEN 2017 THEN r1.dl_2017
              END) = 1 
            THEN
                -- do some thing
                RAISE NOTICE 'processing year of : %', counter;
            END IF;     
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END; 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I assume that all columns `dl_2000` .. `dl_2017` are defined to be `integer` (or `bit`). That is, the table definition looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    /* some columns */
    dl_2000 integer, 
    dl_2001 integer, 
    dl_2002 integer, 
    dl_2003 integer, 
    /* ... */
    dl_2017 integer,
    /* more columns */
) ;
```

You can use instead an `ARRAY` of integers:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    /* some columns */
    dl integer[],
    /* more columns */
) ;
```

(You can have NOT NULL constraints on `dl` in the same way you have them on columns; although written diferently. That is, if necessary, you can have a `CHECK (dl[2000] NOT NULL)`. You cannot have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in those cases.

Then, your function would simply be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update()
    RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE 
    cur SCROLL CURSOR FOR select * from my_tbl;
    r1 RECORD;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur ;
    FOR counter IN  2000..2017 LOOP
        r1 := NULL;
        LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO r1;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

            IF dl[counter] = 1 THEN
                -- do some thing
                RAISE NOTICE 'processing year of : %', counter;
            END IF;     
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END; 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

NOTE: I have not changed the logic in your function, although I am not really sure I would do it this way. At least, I would exchange the two loops. A big one for the cursor, and then inside, one for the columns (or indices of the array).

Answer (score 7):

Using [`row_to_json` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html):

```
do $$
declare
  r json;
  i int;
begin
  for r in 
    select row_to_json(t.*) 
    from (values(1,'a1','a2','a3'),(2,'b1','b2','b3')) as t(x,y11,y12,y13) 
  loop
    raise info '%', r;
    for i in 11..13 loop
      if r->>('y'||i) like '%2' then -- Condition here
        raise info 'Do something for %', r->>('y'||i);
      end if;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

```
INFO:  {"x":1,"y11":"a1","y12":"a2","y13":"a3"}
INFO:  Do something for a2
INFO:  {"x":2,"y11":"b1","y12":"b2","y13":"b3"}
INFO:  Do something for b2
```

---

Using [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
do $$
declare
  r record;
  i int;
begin
  for r in 
    select x, array[y11,y12,y13] as y 
    from (values(1,'a1','a2','a3'),(2,'b1','b2','b3')) as t(x,y11,y12,y13) 
  loop
    raise info '%', r;
    for i in 1..3 loop
      if r.y[i] like '%2' then -- Condition here
        raise info 'Do something for %', r.y[i];
      end if;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

```
INFO:  (1,"{a1,a2,a3}")
INFO:  Do something for a2
INFO:  (2,"{b1,b2,b3}")
INFO:  Do something for b2
```

---

And using [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization):

```
do $$
declare
  r record;
  i int;
begin
  for r in
    with
      test as (
        select * 
        from (values(1,'a1','a2','a3'),(2,'b1','b2','b3')) as t(x,y11,y12,y13)),
      norm as (
        select *, unnest(array[y11,y12,y13]) as y, unnest(array[11,12,13]) as z from test)
    select * from norm
    where y like '%2'  -- Condition here
  loop
    raise info 'Do something for %', r;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

```
INFO:  Do something for (1,a1,a2,a3,a2,12)
INFO:  Do something for (2,b1,b2,b3,b2,12)
```

There are simplified examples, just to show how it could be done in the your more complex task.
But it was tested on the PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 2):

Not to step on @joanolo's toes, but here's a different way to approach the answer, if I am understanding what you're after. I agree that storing the data differently might make querying easier.

Given data like the following:

`CREATE TABLE my_tbl (
id serial primary key,
dl_2000 integer, 
dl_2001 integer, 
dl_2002 integer, 
dl_2003 integer, 
dl_2017 integer);
insert into my_tbl (dl_2000,dl_2001,dl_2002,dl_2003,dl_2017) values
(1,null,null,null,1),
(1,null,1,null,null),
(null,1,null,null,null),
(2,4,5,6,7);`

You can query the columns dynamically for matches:

`DO $$
DECLARE
    rec         RECORD;
    v_col_id    TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT column_name,array_to_string(regexp_matches(column_name,'[0-9]+$'),',')::integer AS year
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 'my_tbl'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT id FROM my_tbl WHERE %I = 1', rec.column_name)
            INTO v_col_id;
        IF ( v_col_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Column % for year %, with id of % matched.', rec.column_name, rec.year, v_col_id;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;`

I used an anonymous plpgsql function for demonstration purposes. It can be written as a named function just as easily.

Comment: (I didn't say there *wasn't* a way. This can be done, but it *ain't* easy ;-)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to imply that your answer was incorrect. I read the question as "I want to retrieve the matches where the column = 1", and thought of the answer in the way above. Your suggestions are perfectly valid.

Comment: No apologies are needed, and no offence taken. Just joking... `DYNAMIC SQL` is not for the faint-hearted, and not easy when learning how to use UDF. It's more complicated to debug than just plain pl/pgSQL, because the "compiler" can help you much less. And that's specially true when you're already in production. If I could avoid it by having a different table definition (or even a different table structure, with a 1:n extra table), I probably would.

Comment: What I want is to compare the value inside r1.selected-row if it is equal 1